# simple .htaccess rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have a .htacces on my server that is supposed to do this:

yo enter to ziced.com/cl/something and rewrites it as ziced.com/cl/index.php?var1=something, however is not working.

you can check that is not working by entering ziced.com/cl/faq versus ziced.com/cl/index.php?var1=faq

here is the .htaccess

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php

# This is the initialization
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
#Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /

#chilean redirect

# /cl/var1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cl/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\*\°\~\,\%\"\'\+\(\)\-]+)/?$ /cl/index.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I might know what the problem is but i dont know how to fix it. The webpage that has the rewrite rule, ziced.com, is an addondomain of metrikstudios.com

ziced.com points to metrikstudios.com/ziced/ so, maybe i should add something like:

```
RewriteRule ^ziced/cl/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\*\°\~\,\%\"\'\+\(\)\-]+)/?$ /cl/index.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Do you have an FAQ directory - if so that could cause one of your preconditions to block the rewrite.  Also have you tried simplifying your regex to just alphanumerics initially in case there's some issue in there (I'm not too hot on regex so can't tell if what you've put would work - but simplifying it and retesting will quickly show if the issue's hidden in there)?

Comment: there's no FAQ directory. The regex is fine, i have used it before. I tried with [a-zA-Z0-9] to check if this was the problem, but didnt work

Comment: Is the /? (before the dollar sign) required?

Comment: Just spotted - you're appending a forward-slash before cl/index.php when you're not including that as part of your test regex.  Adding a forward=slash after ^ or removing from the second part should sort it: RewriteRule ^cl/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\*\°\~\,\%\"\'\+\(\)\-]+)/?$ cl/index.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: not completly sure. I tried removeing it, and didnt work either. Check the update i did to the question at the end of it

Comment: removing the forward-slash wont work. That slash points to the rewrite url, not to match the regex

Comment: Sorry I can't be more helpful on this one - not my area.  It may be worth looking into ways to view the rewritten URL - then you can visually see what's going wrong.  Sadly not my area though.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. Added the .htacces inside the subdirectory ziced (metrikstudios.com/ziced). Then it worked perfect.

Hope it works for someone in the future

Comment: Your original code's problem _may_ have been that the URI you are trying to rewrite _was_ a file or directory, and so didn't trigger either of the RewriteCond tests. You probably didn't need the two RewriteCond tests. Another possibility is that you are using an add-on domain, so it's going to another level of directory that you have to account for.